# Variety consisting of (variety,space) pairs with empty intersections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $V$ be a $d$-dimensional variety in $\mathbb{A}^n\subset \mathbb{P}^n$. Then the set $S$ of $(n-d)$-dimensional affine linear spaces $L$ with $L\cap V=\emptyset$ is not Zariski-dense in the Grassmannian $G=G(n-d+1,n+1)$. ( This is just the same as saying: a generic $(n-d)$-dimensional affine linear space does intersect $V$.)

More is true: if we think of $V$ as being defined by a finite number of equations $F_i(x)=0$ with $F_i$ of bounded degree, then $S$ is contained in a proper subvariety $W$ of $G$ defined by equations whose coefficients are polynomials on the coefficients of all $F_i$. Or, if that's too concrete, consider the consequence I actually need: if $f:X\to Y$ (where $X\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ is a variety, and $Y$ is an irreducible variety) is such that $\mathrm{dim} f^{-1}(y)\geq d$ for every $y$ on $Y$, then the Zariski closure of the set
$$\{(L,y)\in G(n-d+1,n+1) \times Y: L\cap f^{-1}(y) = \emptyset\}$$ has positive codimension in $G(n-d+1,n+1) \times Y$.

All of that is very basic, and we can also prove it from scratch (in fact, my coauthors and I have done so, taking up too much space in our draft of a short paper - potentially distracting from the main point of the subsection). But isn't there a standard reference that we can use?

(Not in Shafarevich, not in Mumford's Red Book, not in Harris...)

Comment: Should we understand that $X=V$?

Comment: No; $X$ is just a variety. $V$ is $f^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: If you wish: it's a family of varieties over a base $Y$. The varieties are the fibers $f^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: In addition to defining the notation, my point is that to make sense of $L\cap f^{-1}(y)$ you need to somehow embed $f^{-1}(y)$ in $\mathbb{A}^n$ (or $\mathbb{P}^n$).

Comment: Sure, $X\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ - sorry for omitting that.